# Storewise product url save programatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, product-urls

I have 2 different website in my Magento. I want to store different `url key` for each website. How to store it programatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I able to achieve this solution by this :

```
public function __construct (
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $productResourceModel
) {
  $this->productResourceModel = $productResourceModel;
}

public function changeUrlByStore($sku, $storeId = 1){
  $product = $this->productFactory->create();
  $productId = $this->productResourceModel->getIdBySku($sku);
  $this->productResourceModel->load($product, $productId);

  $product->setStoreId($storeId);
  $product->setUrlKey(UNIQUE_URL_KEY);
  $this->productResourceModel->saveAttribute($product, 'url_key');
}
```